# I soundly slept, but when I rose

Tags: rhyme, no-computers, cryptic-clues

*I soundly slept, but when I rose,

my papers showed disheveled prose.

At once I knew the imp had been

again among the realms of men...*

1. Minimum ward to get by on (6)
2. To celebrate their love of geometric puzzles, the friends had a tangy... (7)
3. Sasquatch rumps are soft but years are the softest (4)
4. When his son gets on his nerve, shot sad rink from Moe’s (5)
5. Unfinished rotunda is still lace (7)
6. Because of the medicine, my turtle's sealed! (7)
7. I always seal sin the supermarket, checking for nuts (6)

*Now clues are solved, alas, I fear

the fiend has fled to god knows where.

Consult the runes, unearth the text

and find out where he’s heading next...*

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once again, these are Printer's Devilry clues.

1.

> Minimum wa**ge is ha**rd to get by on (6)

2.

> To celebrate their love of geometric puzzles, the friends had a tang**ram part**y... (7)

3.

> Sasquatch rumps are soft but ye**ti re**ars are the softest (4)

4.

> When his son gets on his nerves, Ho**mer ge**ts a drink from Moe’s (5)

5.

> Unfinished rotunda is still lac**king dom**e (7) *(Thanks, Gareth!)*

6.

> Because of the medicine, my turtle's s**hell is h**ealed! (7)

7.

> I always s**can cer**eals in the supermarket, checking for nuts (6) *(thanks, Gareth! (again))*

Solution grid:

> [image]

Rearranging the highlighted letters tells us that the devil went

> [down to **GEORGIA**!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil_Went_Down_to_Georgia)

Comment: 5a is KINGDOM (lacking dome)

Comment: 7a is CANCER (scan cereals)